# Can't figure out how to generate & view logs for nodeJs bot on Bot Service

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-functions, azure-bot-service

I deployed my nodeJs bot to Bot Service recently, and i can't seems to figure out how to generate and view it's logs.

- when i try to enable logging, i constantly getting an unknown error
- Looking at the log files on the server, there is no file who logs the node application
- Tried to log to Application insights, without success.

help?

Comment: Feedback regarding your issue can be seen at [Logging issues with bot service](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/562027-azure-bot-service/suggestions/17326249-logging-issues-with-bot-service), you can monitor it's status for any update.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, i'll wait for the fix

Comment: Found this workaround for now - https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1909

Comment: Could you open another question or expand this one on your App Insights issues? That should work fine.

Comment: I will go with the workaround for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your bot is hosted through Azure via an App Service, you should be able to see logging from your NodeJS application by performing the following steps:

**Enabling Logging**

1. Click on the App Service box on your Azure dashboard, or navigate to the resource via the top search bar.
2. In the side menu, under **Monitoring,** navigate to **Diagnostic logs.**
3. Make sure that **Application Logging (Filesystem)** is turned on.
4. Now, in the root directory of your NodeJS application **\site\wwwroot**, you want to create a file named **IISNode.yml** and inside of it write the line `loggingEnabled: true`. This will enable your application to write `stderr` and `stdout` to the log stream.
5. From here, you just need to access the log stream of your application, and there are 3 ways.

**Accessing the Log Stream**

Personally, I prefer using the **Azure Command-Line Interface**, which you can easily install using the node package manager or **npm.**

To install the Azure CLI, issue the following command on your terminal:

`npm install -g azure-cli`

or `sudo npm install -g azure-cli` if you need root permission.

If you need more information on how to install the Azure CLI [look here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/xplat-cli-install)

Now you have to log into your Azure account through the Azure CLI so that it can access your subscription. This is done via `azure login`.

Once you have finished logging in through the command line, you need to switch to service management mode with the command `azure config mode asm`.

Then you can use `azure site list` to get a list of your current Azure sites.

In the list, find the site that you want the logs for, and find its name in the **Name** column. Then use the command `azure site log tail <sitename>` and the terminal will start to output live logs straight from your application!

**Other Options**

The above method is only 1 of the 3 methods you can use to access these logs. If you want more information on the other 2 methods then [follow this link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-debug#accessing-logs)

That above link also contains a lot of the information I outlined in my post.

I hope this helped!