# Error when enabling diagnostic logs - Azure Botframework

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, kik

I'm having a problem where my Bot Framework bot stops responding to Kik.

I'd like to enable the diagnostic logs in Azure, but when I click "save", I get the error message "Failed to update web app logs settings for autoCompeteBot. There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments."

Any idea how I can avoid this error and see my logs?

Thanks!

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537711/cant-figure-out-how-to-generate-view-logs-for-nodejs-bot-on-bot-service

Comment: @AaronChen-MSFT thanks aaron. when i try that, i'm getting error: 

    Exception while executing function: Functions.messages. mscorlib: D:\home\site\wwwroot\messages\index.js:93
  default: connector.listen( default: withLogging )
                             ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token default
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    ...

Comment: @AaronChen-MSFT putting  default: token in brackets cleared the error, but logging page still says "Application logs are switched off. You can turn them on using the 'Diagnostic logs' settings." So not sure if that's doing anything.

Comment: could you provide your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the answer by @hailiu2586 here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1909.

Replace the following line in your messages/index.js

```
module.exports = { default: connector.listen() }
```

With:

```
var listener = connector.listen();
var withLogging = function(context, req) {
    console.log = context.log;
    listener(context, req);
}

module.exports = { default: withLogging  }
```

After that done, `console.log()` should work.